# What will be the query to retrieve these records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Input table: **Sales Data**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
| Child         | Parent        | Level     | Sales     |
+---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
| All Region    | All Region    | 1         |  1000000  |
| Africa Region | All Region    | 2         |   159816  |
| America       | All Region    | 2         |   114054  |
| Asia          | All Region    | 2         |    74028  |
| Europe Region | All Region    | 2         |   116766  |
| Africa        | Africa Region | 3         |    81954  |
| Asia Pacific  | Asia          | 3         |   144306  |
| Europe        | Europe Region | 3         |     1440  |
| North America | America       | 3         |     8185  |
| South America | America       | 3         |     8440  | 
| Argentina     | South America | 4         |      470  |
| Australia     | Asia Pacific  | 4         |     9040  |
| Pakistan      | Asia Pacific  | 4         |      705  | 
| South Africa  | Africa        | 4         |       45  |
| Tunisia       | Africa        | 4         |      385  | 
| Uruguay       | South America | 4         |      420  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Level

- 1 = all regions
- 2 = region
- 3 = subregion
- 4 = country

I need to output records there will be two columns one is CHILD another is `MAX_Sale`, in the `MAX_Sale` column only maximum sales amount will be there among the siblings of the corresponding child data.

Example:

```
+-----------+------------+
| Childs    | Max_sales  |
+-----------+------------+
| Austrlia  |   9040     |
| Pakistan  |   9040     |
| S.Africa  |    385     |
| Tunisia   |    385     |
+------------------------+
```

As Australia and Pakistan both belong to same parents and Australia has max sales value

Comment: What's your *input* here? Will you always be retrieving all children of a single parent? If not, should the max be considered across all children or only those that are selected?

Comment: Yes,all children of a single parent.Max will be calculated according to the siblings ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a window function (`row_number`) to get this result:

```
select child, MAX_Sale
from  (
        select child, 
               sales as MAX_Sale,
               row_number() over (partition by parent order by sales desc) as rn
        from   t
      ) sub
where rn = 1
```

... assuming your table is called *t*. Replace as needed.

Output is:

```
 Child         | MAX_Sale
---------------+---------
 Tunisia       |     385
 Africa        |   81954
 All Region    | 1000000
 South America |    8440
 Asia Pacific  |  144306
 Australia     |    9040
 Europe        |    1440
 Argentina     |     470
```

Depending on your needs, you may still need to filter by level, and apply a certain sort order.

#### Listing all regions

If however you need to list all regions, with the sales of the sibling with the best sales, then:

```
select child, 
       first_value(sales) over (partition by parent order by sales desc) as MAX_Sale
from   t
```

The output:

```
Child         | MAX_Sale
--------------+----------
Tunisia       |     385
South Africa  |     385
Africa        |   81954
All Region    | 1000000
Africa Region | 1000000
Europe Region | 1000000
America       | 1000000
Asia          | 1000000
South America |    8440
North America |    8440
Asia Pacific  |  144306
Australia     |    9040
Pakistan      |    9040
Europe        |    1440
Argentina     |     470
Uruguay       |     470
```

[`first_value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) is an ["analytic function"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234(v=sql.110).aspx), used in the context of "window functions": the [`over` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) defines a window to apply the window function to.

Comment: Thanks! Your second query gives desired output.But ,I am having trouble as I dont know First_value and partition  things,as I am newbie ,could please explain or give some links ?

Comment: Maybe this link will help: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2012-window-function-basics/

Answer (score 1):

Hi if I have understood correctly you need a query similar to this:

```
SELECT
Child,
MAx_Sales
FROM table1 inner join
(
  SELECT
  Parent,
  max(Sales) as Max_sales
  FROM  table1
  GROUP BY Parent 
) as table2
on table1.Parent = table2.Parent
```

Comment: Try now...you changed the example and now I have understood better the result that you need (or I hope so)...

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code would work for you:

```
Select child, Sales as Max_Sales 
from table A
where Sales >= All (Select Sales from table B
                     Where A.level=B.Level
                       and A.Parent=B.Parent)
```

This is according to below understanding
Say, SubRegion A as 4 child countries p,q,r,s then we need name and sales of country among the four having maximum sales.